# refresh datagridview when ever i hit insert button

Tags: datagridview, refresh

i have searched for the answer for this particular question for way too long but i get no clear help.

can you help me with refreshing the datagrid view . when ever i click insert button else i have to restart my program to see recently updated data. 
i have tried using datagridview.refresh(); 
and datagridview.update(); in both datagridview and insert button code but it wont work. this is my code for inserting data in database :

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DatabaseConnection dbcon = new DatabaseConnection();
    dbcon.OpenDbConnection();
    dbcon.commandConnection();

    gender1();

    string query = "Insert into Employee_personal_info (Last_Name,Middle_Name,First_Name,Phone_Number,Email_Address,Permanent_Address,Temporary_Address,Gender,userimage) values ('" + textBoxLastName.Text + "','" + textBoxMiddleName.Text + "', '" + textBoxFirstName.Text + "','" + textBoxPhoneNumber.Text + "','" + textBoxEmailAddress.Text + "','" + textBoxPermanentAdd.Text + "','" + textBoxTemporaryAdd.Text + "','" + gender1() + "','"+textBox_imagepath.Text+"') ";

    string query2 = "Select @@Identity";
    int ID;

    try
    {
        dbcon.commandExecuteNonQuery(query);

        ID = (int)dbcon.commandExecuteScalar(query2);

        string query1 = " Insert into Employee_company_info (E_ID,Department, Post, Duty_shift, Date_Hired, Date_Released) values ("+ID+",'" + comboBoxDepartment.Text + "','" + comboBoxPost.Text + "','" + comboBoxDutyShift.Text + "','" + dateTimePicker1.Value + "','" + dateTimePicker2.Value + "') ";

        dbcon.commandExecuteNonQuery(query1);
        MessageBox.Show("data inserted sucessfully");


    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(exp.Message);
        MessageBox.Show("data not inserted ");

    }
}
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: where is your code when you load your data and attach it in datagrid?

Answer (score 2):

Refresh the page to view the changes.

because, **the page, view or the Data-grid is not being refreshed or reloaded automatically with the new data from the table, once you have done something in code behind!**

`Here, you are not updating the datagrid, instead you are updating the database table directly.` So, using `datagridview.refresh();` or `datagridview.update();` will be of no use.

use `location.reload();` to refresh the page.

Or you could `use ajax instead, if you don't want the page to reload!`

**Here is the changed code:**

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DatabaseConnection dbcon = new DatabaseConnection();
    dbcon.OpenDbConnection();
    dbcon.commandConnection();

    gender1();

    string query = "Insert into Employee_personal_info (Last_Name,Middle_Name,First_Name,Phone_Number,Email_Address,Permanent_Address,Temporary_Address,Gender,userimage) values ('" + textBoxLastName.Text + "','" + textBoxMiddleName.Text + "', '" + textBoxFirstName.Text + "','" + textBoxPhoneNumber.Text + "','" + textBoxEmailAddress.Text + "','" + textBoxPermanentAdd.Text + "','" + textBoxTemporaryAdd.Text + "','" + gender1() + "','"+textBox_imagepath.Text+"') ";

    string query2 = "Select @@Identity";
    int ID;

    try
    {
        dbcon.commandExecuteNonQuery(query);

        ID = (int)dbcon.commandExecuteScalar(query2);

        string query1 = " Insert into Employee_company_info (E_ID,Department, Post, Duty_shift, Date_Hired, Date_Released) values ("+ID+",'" + comboBoxDepartment.Text + "','" + comboBoxPost.Text + "','" + comboBoxDutyShift.Text + "','" + dateTimePicker1.Value + "','" + dateTimePicker2.Value + "') ";

        dbcon.commandExecuteNonQuery(query1);
        MessageBox.Show("data inserted sucessfully");

        location.reload(); //**Here he is**

    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(exp.Message);
        MessageBox.Show("data not inserted ");

    }
}
```